# JQUERY: Getting JSON Data from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get, getjson

I am trying to use `$.getJSON()` to get JSON data from websites. Below is the code I am using

the website I am trying to get the JSON data from is [this](https://whattomine.com/coins/4.json).

this code worked perfectly fine when querying data from this [link](http://time.jsontest.com),
but it does not work for the first link..
Why is this?

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://whattomine.com/coins/4.json', function(data) {

    var text = `Rewards: ${data.estimated_rewards}`


    $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
</script>
```

Comment: why dont you try to console ${data.estimated_rewards}. see what you get from there

Comment: and your first link print valid json?

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle demonstrating the issue.  You can see the cors error in the console: https://jsfiddle.net/shawnoakley/L59pn8u6/10/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not making this request from `https://whattomine.com/` to that site. Unless request site and origin site are same, according to `CORS policy` you cannot make **XMLHttpRequest** to any site which has `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.

Please check your browser console there should be an error notification about it.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the above.  As stated, looks like there's a cors issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/shawnoakley/L59pn8u6/10/

Comment: Thank you both Tamim and Shawn.

Comment: Can you please kindly point me in the right direction, as that I can successfully get the JSON data from the said website? Thanks

Comment: Which backend programming language are you using for your webpage? e.g (PHP/Ruby/ASP) ? @안지상

Comment: My goal is to get that "estimated_rewards" data and write a script that will input the data into a google spreadsheets. I had no idea that it would be this difficult :(
I'm just trying to automate a process, but it appears that there's far more to it than expected

Comment: The easiest way I can think of that you can use any backend programming language like PHP / javascript to fetch json from that URL, which will not cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

**cross-origin** requests are always forbidden, it's a security policy for all browsers.

or you have to make the site return a header for allow **cross-origin** request:

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'